# Property 'connectionField' does not exist on type 'ObjectDefinitionBlock<"Query">

Tags: nexus, graphql-js

I'm trying to build this project and I'm getting error that property doesn't exist.

What's the issue?

https://www.prisma.io/blog/fullstack-nextjs-graphql-prisma-2-fwpc6ds155

./graphql/types/Link.ts:20:7
Type error: Property 'connectionField' does not exist on type 'ObjectDefinitionBlock<"Query">'.

18 |   type: 'Query',
19 |   definition(t) {

> 20 |     t.connectionField('links', {
> |       ^
> 21 |       type: Link,
> 22 |       resolve: async (_, { after, first }, ctx) => {
> 23 |         const offset = after ? cursorToOffset(after) + 1 : 0;
> error Command failed with exit code 1.
> info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
> hanymorcos@Hanys-MBP awesome-links %

Comment: you have to run it.

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out? It's confusing because the plugin seems to be a run-time thing that happens at the end, so how do we use it without type errors?

Comment: @tslater by running he means `npx run dev` instead of `npx run build`

Comment: meant to say npm not npx